# how to connect java and mysql using mysql connector java 5.1.12

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I'm still a beginner in java. I dont have any idea on how to import the files that I have downloaded into my java class.
Its in this path:

```
E:\Users\user\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12
```

I don't know what to do with the files I extracted from the file that I have downloaded in the mysql site for me to connect my java application and mysql database.

I'm using Netbeans 6.8. And have also installed wampserver.

ive already check out 
This: [Java: Trouble connecting to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118369/java-trouble-connecting-to-mysql)
and this: [Connecting to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640910/connecting-to-a-mysql-database)

But they don't seem to have answers on how to make use of the mysql java connector file from mysql site.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your project in your project explorer and click on properties.

From there go to libraries -> add jar file then go to whatever .jar file you want to import.

That should add the jar file to your project classpath.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640910/connecting-to-a-mysql-database/1640931#1640931) to the second question you already found here on SO is a good reference! In addition you simply have to make sure, that the mysql connector library is on the classpath. That should be all.